# Mapping key combinations like Windows + L to @ sign

Tags: shortcut-keys

There are many questions out there but none worked or apply to my situation:
I often switch between Mac OSX and Ubuntu and the @, copy & paste key combinations are driving me mad.
How can I map (on Ubuntu side) the super + c combination to copy, the super + v combination to paste and super + L or alt + L to @?

Until yet I figured out that you can get the key codes via xev: l = keycode 46 but it does not work for the super / windows key.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, since Im not running (Unity) Ubuntu I dont have the full answer.

### First idea:

Try changing your keyboard layout from System Settings > Keyboard. Some languages have a Mac version of the layout. That might have the @ key at a suitable place for you.

### Second idea:

Try adding a new shortcut key combination for copy and paste. The old one would still work, but that would be less annoying. You can maybe find it somewhere in System Settings > Keyboard or Input Devices.

---

The Super/Meta/Windows key isnt registered because it is one of the modifier keys (just like Alt and Shift) and those are not handled like normal keys in Linux.